# How can I add a custom column to my Serilog MS SQL Server sink?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, serilog

I am trying to add a custom column to my logging database, however I get a TargetInvocationException.

It was working before I added `MSSqlServerSettingsSection` (so without the custom column), so I'm probably missing something there.

However, looking at the example at https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver I can't figure out what I need.

MSSqlServer sink settings:

```
<MSSqlServerSettingsSection>
    <Columns>
      <add ColumnName="JobId" 
           DataType="nvarchar"
           DataLength="256"
           AllowNull="True"/>
    </Columns>
</MSSqlServerSettingsSection>
```

app.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="MSSqlServerSettingsSection" type="Serilog.Configuration.MSSqlServerConfigurationSection, Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer"/>
  </configSections>
  <MSSqlServerSettingsSection configSource="Configs\Shared.Serilog.MSSqlServerSettings.config" />
  <appSettings>
    <add key="serilog:using:MSSqlServer" value="Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:MSSqlServer.connectionString" value="Server=127.0.0.1; Database=LogDB; User Id=Serilog; Password=Password123;" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:MSSqlServer.tableName" value="Logs" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:MSSqlServer.autoCreateSqlTable" value="false" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:MSSqlServer.restrictedToMinimumLevel" value="Verbose" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Creation query:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Logs]
(
    [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Message] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [MessageTemplate] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [Level] nvarchar(128) NULL,
    [TimeStamp] datetime NOT NULL,
    [Exception] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [Properties] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [JobId] nvarchar(256) NULL 

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Logs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC), 
)
```

DI using unity:

```
container.RegisterInstance<ILogger>(new LoggerConfiguration()
                                                .Enrich
                                                .FromLogContext()
                                                .ReadFrom
                                                .AppSettings()
                                                .CreateLogger());
Log.Logger = container.Resolve<ILogger>();
```

I have tried to debug with Selflog, but the log file is empty:

```
var file = File.CreateText("Self.log");
Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(TextWriter.Synchronized(file));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm getting the following exception

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: 'Unrecognized attribute 
'DataLength'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.'
```

Not sure why this is, according to the documentation it should be correct. 
Removing this line gave me the same issue on 'AllowNull' .

Removing both lines seems to work.